# Dividing in Linux with date in two files

Tags: linux

I must take 100 located in File2 and divide it by 5 located in File1. This has to be done in a script. The book is not too clear on how to proceed. I have tried many different iterations of the script but always come back with an error referencing "/". I have put the expression in backtick, double parenthesis and brackets. The OS is Red Hat Linux.

The script:
cat File1 File2

```
#!/bin/bash
var3=$[$var2 / $var1]
```

This is what I get:

```
var1=5
var2=100
/home/Student/MyFiles/student/week3prog3student.scr: line 3: / : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

Comment: The syntax depends on the shell you are using, but if you check the manual page for your shell it should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
var3=$(($var2 / $var1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nifty way of doing floating point division that is scriptable.  Bash only does integer division via $((x/y))

```
var2=10
var1=3
echo "scale=2; $var2/$var1" | bc
```

scale is the number of decimal digits after the decimal point.